# Use user.config instead of app.config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, unity-container

Can someone give me a simple example on how to user user-settings instead of application-settings? I need to have user-specific Microsoft Unity section, but the config won't be created for the user on application startup. Also, I can't use the Visual Studio gui to create those settings. I need to modify some of the mappings during runtime as well.

This is what I need in the User-Config (which should be placed in the user's appdata)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="MyUnityContainer" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyProgram.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString" connectionString="aConnectionString" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <MyUnityContainer>
        <typeAliases>
          <!-- type aliases -->
        </typeAliases>
        <containers>
          <container>
            <types>
              <!-- types -->
            </types>
            <extensions>
              <add type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Interception, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception" />
            </extensions>
            <extensionConfig>
              <add name="interception" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationElement, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration"></add>
            </extensionConfig>
          </container>
        </containers>
      </MyUnityContainer>
   </configuration>
```

I need to load this on application startup, but the config file for the user will not be created! How can I make my program create the user-specific config automatically during startup, if it does not exist already?

Comment: Required files are generally copied/generated during installation. If it isn't there from that point on then this is a somewhat exceptional circumstance, only with the difference that it's on of those we can gracefully handle.

Comment: How? For all users? What if a user is added? .NET ought to create the user.config file automatically during startup, if it does not exist or the assembly version has changed. Yet, no such file is created, although I can read the path property for the user.config.

Comment: If a new user is added then that is where your own logic comes into play - .NET can't just decide to create files under `AppData` for every enabled application when a new user is added (among other things, what if it didn't have permissions to do so?). You'll have to do _some_ work and write logic which checks+copies+modifies as required.

Comment: Well, in fact, .NET can and will.

Comment: Oh, but it's just deciding to pick on you in this instance?

Comment: Yes, for some reason. But this works generally, for example if you use the builtin settings. You can define user-scope config parameters and a user.config will be created for each user, who starts the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by copying the whole config to app data and load it from there via a path mapping. This works.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFile.ExeConfigFilename = exeFilePath; //somewhere in appdata in my case
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile,ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

App.config is stored in application root while user.config is stored in user profile. User.config overrides the App.config settings

Answer (score 0):

I thought user.config overrides were only available for the appSetting configuration section.

so you would have:

```
<appSettings file="user.config">
```